# Is there a way to automate creation of dashboards on Grafana as and when new namespaces are added in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, health-monitoring

I have been checking few references online for this particular use case but no solution was just a complete fit. I have a use case where I am considering to create a multi-tenant Kubernetes cluster with each tenant occupying a namespace. Since I would like to add each new tenant dynamically to my cluster, I would like to get the Monitoring of that namespace in Grafana with a predefined set of rules auto-configured.

Comment: grafana dashboard should auto update on new namespaces , but im not sure if there is multi tenancy in there

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://grafana.com/docs/guides/basic_concepts/#organization ?